# How to use left join in jpql

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpql

Hey guys this query works fine in oracle (sqldeveloper) but when I try to use it on jpql named query it gives me an error im assuming its related to the way im doing the outer join but Im not really sure, I need the outer join to be able to get the MsMenu even if they are null.

Query made on oracle (working):

```
select ac.accecodi, ac.accenomb, m.menucodi, m.menunomb from ms_usuario u, ms_grupo g, ms_gruporol gr, ms_rol r, ms_acrol ar, ms_acces ac 
left outer JOIN ms_menu m ON ac.menucodi = m.menucodi where ar.accecodi = ac.accecodi and r.rolcodi = ar.rolcodi and gr.rolcodi = r.rolcodi
and g.grupcodi = gr.grupcodi and u.grupcodi = g.grupcodi and u.usuausua='CP9991115';
```

Query on jpql (giving me the error):

```
@NamedQuery(name = MsAcceso.buscarTodosAccesoPorUsuario, query = "SELECT modelo from MsAcceso modelo, MsUsuario u, MsGrupo g, MsGrupoRol gr, MsRol r, MsAccesoRol ar"
            + " left outer JOIN MsMenu m ON modelo.msMenu.menucodi = m.menucodi where ar.msAcceso.accecodi = modelo.accecodi and r.rolcodi = ar.msRol.rolcodi and gr.msRol.rolcodi = r.rolcodi"
            + " and g.grupcodi = gr.msGrupo.grupcodi and u.msGrupo.grupcodi = g.grupcodi and u.usuausua=:usuausua")
```

The error im getting:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "T12"."MENUCODI": identificador no válido
```

It says menucodi its not a valid identifier, but it is my table MsMenu primary key its menucodi, so that why im guessing its the way im doing the left outer join, any help is appreciated.

My MsAcceso class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MS_ACCES")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = MsAcceso.buscarTodosAcceso, query = "SELECT modelo from MsAcceso modelo order by modelo.accecodi asc"),
        @NamedQuery(name = MsAcceso.buscarTodosAccesoActivos, query = "SELECT modelo from MsAcceso modelo where UPPER(modelo.acceacti) = 'S' order by modelo.accecodi asc"),
        @NamedQuery(name = MsAcceso.buscarAccesoActivoPorCodigo, query = "SELECT modelo from MsAcceso modelo where modelo.accecodi=:accecodi and UPPER(modelo.acceacti) = 'S'"),
        @NamedQuery(name = MsAcceso.buscarAccesoPorCodigo, query = "SELECT modelo from MsAcceso modelo where modelo.accecodi=:accecodi"),
        @NamedQuery(name = MsAcceso.buscarAccesoPorNombre, query = "SELECT modelo from MsAcceso modelo where modelo.accenomb=:accenomb"),
        @NamedQuery(name = MsAcceso.buscarTodosAccesoActivosPorPrograma, query = "SELECT a from MsAcceso a, MsPrograma p"
                + " where" + " UPPER(a.acceacti)='S' " + " and a.msPrograma.progcodi = p.progcodi "
                + "and p.prognomb=:prognomb order by a.accecodi asc"),
        @NamedQuery(name = MsAcceso.buscarTodosAccesoPorPrograma, query = "SELECT a from MsAcceso a, MsPrograma p"
                + " where" + " a.msPrograma.progcodi = p.progcodi "
                + "and p.prognomb=:prognomb order by a.accecodi asc"),
        @NamedQuery(name = MsAcceso.buscarTodosAccesoPorUsuario, query = "SELECT modelo from MsAcceso modelo, MsUsuario u, MsGrupo g, MsGrupoRol gr, MsRol r, MsAccesoRol ar"
                + " left outer JOIN MsMenu m ON modelo.msMenu.menucodi = m.menucodi where ar.msAcceso.accecodi = modelo.accecodi and r.rolcodi = ar.msRol.rolcodi and gr.msRol.rolcodi = r.rolcodi"
                + " and g.grupcodi = gr.msGrupo.grupcodi and u.msGrupo.grupcodi = g.grupcodi and u.usuausua=:usuausua")

})

@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "SEQ_ACCESO", name = "seqAcceso", allocationSize = 1)
public class MsAcceso implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public final static String buscarTodosAcceso = "co.com.codesa.seguridad.dominio.Acceso.buscarTodosAcceso";
    public final static String buscarTodosAccesoActivos = "co.com.codesa.seguridad.dominio.Acceso.buscarTodosAccesoActivos";
    public final static String buscarAccesoActivoPorCodigo = "co.com.codesa.seguridad.dominio.Acceso.buscarAccesoActivoPorCodigo";
    public final static String buscarAccesoPorCodigo = "co.com.codesa.seguridad.dominio.Acceso.buscarAccesoPorCodigo";
    public final static String buscarAccesoPorNombre = "co.com.codesa.seguridad.dominio.Acceso.buscarAccesoPorNombre";
    public final static String buscarTodosAccesoActivosPorPrograma = "co.com.codesa.seguridad.dominio.Acceso.buscarTodosAccesoActivosPorPrograma";
    public final static String buscarTodosAccesoPorPrograma = "co.com.codesa.seguridad.dominio.Acceso.buscarTodosAccesoPorPrograma";
    public final static String buscarTodosAccesoPorUsuario = "co.com.codesa.seguridad.dominio.Acceso.buscarTodosAccesoPorUsuario";

    private Long accecodi;
    private String acceacti;
    private String accecntx;
    private String accedesc;
    private Date accefsys;
    private String acceip;
    private String accelogi;
    private String accenomb;
    private String accepuert;
    private String accetitu;
    private String accefsysS;
    private MsMenu msMenu;
    private MsPrograma msPrograma;
    private List<MsAccesoRol> msAcrols;
```

If you need to see more code let me know :)

Comment: @APC hey mate thanks for checking out my question, modelo its the same like in the first query "ms_acces ac" just that I name it modelo instead of ac, and modelo.menucodi won't work because MsAcceso doesn't has a menucodi attribute, it has a msMenu which does have the menucodi attribute

Comment: I appreciate the help mate